# facebook-passport authentication using ionic2 and express app

Tags: node.js, express, ionic2, facebook-authentication, passport-facebook

So I am trying to add facebook authentication to my ionic2 app using express and passportjs. I almost got it working except the last part of redirecting the user back to ionic2 app after authorization. my both the apps are working on different ports; ionic2 running on http://localhost:8100 and express app for backend stuff running on http://localhost:8000

These are the steps I followed:

1. Created app on developers.facebook.com and got the App ID and secret ID.
2. Under Products>Facebook>settings, I have added callBack url as

[image]

3. Then in my express app which is running on localhost:8000, I have added facebook authentication strategy as shown in https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-facebook which is something like this:

   ```
   passport.use(new FacebookStrategy({
      clientID: FACEBOOK_APP_ID,
      clientSecret: FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET,
      callbackURL: "http://localhost:8000/auth/facebook/callback"
   },
   function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, cb) {
       User.findOrCreate({ facebookId: profile.id }, function (err, user) {
         return cb(err, user);
       });
   }
   ));

    app.get('/auth/facebook',
    passport.authenticate('facebook'));

   app.get('/auth/facebook/callback',
       passport.authenticate('facebook', { failureRedirect: '/login' }),
       function(req, res) {
      // Successful authentication, redirect home.
      res.redirect('/');      //how to redirect back to ionic app instead of /
   });
   ```

   so now whenever user clicks on facebook button on ionic2 app its going to facebook authentication page and once successfully authenticated it's redirecting back to localhost:8000/auth/facebook/callback as expected but I want to redirect back to ionic app. how can I solve this problem? Need some guidance to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you need but I was able to open up a new window that handles the facebook authentication. This was done in my provider below: My successRedirect looks like this:

```
public loginWithFacebook(callback : (data : any) => any){
    this.callback = callback;
    this.childWindow = this.nativeWindow.open(this.authEndpoint);
    this.closeTimer = setInterval(() => {
      if (this.childWindow.closed){
        clearInterval(this.closeTimer);
        this.childWindow = null;
        this.closeTimer = null;
        var passedJson = this.http.get(this.checkEndpoint).map(res => res.json());
        passedJson.subscribe(data => {
          this.callback(data);
        });
      }
    }, 500);
  }
```

This checks to see if the window is closed. The problem is that I have to automatically close it. I simply made an html page that the success redirect renders that closes the new window created. Here is my `successRedirect`

```
router.get('/api/auth/facebook/success', function (req, res) {
    res.render('after-auth');
});
```

Make sure that with your express app you have your view engine set up in your app.js.

```
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'html');
```

Your views/after-auth.html should look like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.close();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

This now closes the new window. The only problem I am still having is that the session doesnt seem to save when I try and do the next call. `req.user` seems to be `undefined` for me